What is Causing These Gaps After Abbreviated Words with Typewriter Text?
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\texttt{Mr. Comiskey refused to see Mr. Jackson.}
\end{document}

which generates the sentence:

What causes the gaps after the abbreviated words? And how do I fix it?

TeX inserts a larger space following the end of a sentence and it cannot distinguish between the dot in Mr. and the full-stop at the end of a sentence. So you need
Mr.\ Comiskey

or, if you want to prevent a line break between the title and the name
Mr.~Comiskey

This effect doesn't depend on the use of typewriter. The same is true for roman and sans. However, the effect may be more visible if you are using a monowidth typewriter.

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\texttt{Mr. Comiskey refused to see Mr. Jackson.}

\texttt{Mr.\ Comiskey refused to see Mr.\ Jackson.}

\texttt{Mr.~Comiskey refused to see Mr.~Jackson.}

Mr. Comiskey refused to see Mr. Jackson.

Mr.\ Comiskey refused to see Mr.\ Jackson.

Mr.~Comiskey refused to see Mr.~Jackson.
\end{document}


+1. You could also mention \frenchspacing, which turns off the spacefactor business entirely.

@Mico true, but that might be taken as a suggestion and I don't think it is appropriate for English .... or is it proper for a monowidth? as far as I remember, my parents always typed 2 spaces when they used to use typewriters.

Typing 2 spaces at the end of a sentence is frowned on these days, but in contexts such as one in which the sample sentence might "natively" occur, it really does make a difference in comprehension.  I'm old enough to have participated in the data entry (by keypunch) of the Brown Corpus, still used for linguistic exploration.  Every period had to be identified as to its function.  Useless otherwise.  (I agree with Knuth in this regard.)

@barbarabeeton I'm afraid you've lost me. do you mean 2 spaces was used to mark dots as full-stops? (sorry, I'm not sure whether 'period' and 'full-stop' are always equivalent.) and Knuth endorses that? my parents would mostly have been typing stuff destined for editing, (literal) copy-pasting and finally typesetting once pages were made up. so te 2 spaces wouldn't necessarily have ended up on the printed page.

Thank you for this answer.

'@cfr -- "Period" is the name of the symbol.  In the US, I'm not aware of a single different term for "the end of a sentence", although I'm familiar with "full stop" being used for that elsewhere.  The extra space is used after the period only at the end of a sentence; but unless it's clear in a text file which periods do end sentences, it's not easy to tell the difference.  If a text contains a lot of abbreviations, the distinction must be made explicitly; Knuth considered that ends of sentences were more common than abbreviations in most texts, and built that assumption into TeX.

@barbarabeeton well, yes, I do know that. I asked about 'period' precisely because I wasn't sure whether it was the US equivalent of 'full stop' or not. apparently not. (which makes me wonder about the use of 'such and such period' where we'd say 'such and such full stop' - I always assumed these meant the same ...).

@barbarabeeton or did you just mean I should add \frenchspacing ...?
